# How do I access certain parts of an array for use with flot charts?

Tags: php, arrays, flot

I've got an array below via print_r, however I need to only use part of this so I can use it in flot charts.

> Array ( [success] => 1 [timestamp] => 1383824357 [data] => Array ( [0]
>   => Array ( [label] => customer1 [SUM(value)] => 12345) [1] => Array ( [label] => customer2 [SUM(value)] => 67890) [2] => Array ( [label] =>
>   customer3 [SUM(value)] => 11223 ) [3] => Array ( [label] => customer4
>   [SUM(value)] => 33445 ) ) )

The format that flot charts want is like so (with the above data used):

```
[
    { label: "customer1",  data: 12345},
    { label: "customer2",  data: 67890},
    { label: "customer3",  data: 11223},
    { label: "customer4",  data: 34455}
];
```

Does anyone know how I can go about accessing the data as above?

Comment: Prepare new array for your requirements or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so u basically want to change the "data" key with the "SUM(value)" key and then accessing the array? if so u can use this snippet:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($data);

function array_change_key_name( $orig, $new, &$array ) {
  foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
    $res[ $k === $orig ? $new : $k ] = ( (is_array($v)||is_object($v)) ? array_change_key_name( $orig, $new, $v ) : $v );
  }
  return $res;
}

$new = array_change_key_name("data" ,"SUM(value)" , $data);
echo json_encode($new);
?>
```

EDIT: The code change the key data in the key SUM(value) ... if i understand well u want the opposit ... just invert the function parameters like this

$new = array_change_key_name("SUM(value)" ,"data" , $data);

there is also another way to do the same thing, but u will have to change the query from:

```
Select SUM(value) etc etc
```

to

```
Select SUM(value) as data etc etc
```

and the DB will handle all for u :)

Answer (score 1):

Just convert convert it to a JSON object:

```
$json = json_encode($array['data']);
```

Then you've got the structure you need.

You might need to change the field names from `value` to `data` aswell.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($array['data']); // $array is the name of your array
```

You can do:

```
foreach ($myArray as $val) {
    echo $val['data'].'<br />';
    // Do whatever you want to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this May be it will Work . I didn't tested ...

```
 $myArray = "Your array";
 $data = $myArray['data'];
 $js_ar = '"';
    foreach($data as $record)
    {
        $js_ar .= '{ "label": $record[label],  data: $record[SUM(value)]}';

    }
    $js_ar = '"';
    $json_data = json_encode($js_ar);

    print_r ($json_data);
```